# MinimalPolynomial[] for expressions containing symbols

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I’m using Mathematica to solve some simple equations relating to geometry, and subsequently hard-coding those solutions in a different language†. Rather than have many pages of code, it would be more concise to code the solutions as a root of a polynomial.

Let’s take:

```
Solve[{
   dist^2 == xstep^2 + ((h - 2 r)/(NR - 1))^2,
   dist^2 == (w - 2 r - NC xstep)^2 + (h/2 - r - dist/2)^2
         },{xstep, dist}]
```

That generates a “very large output”, heavy with fractions and square roots and fourth roots. Obviously the two solved variables are the roots of quartic equations.

Please, is there a version of MinimalPolynomial[] that will work on expressions containing symbols? All that’s wanted is the five coefficients of dist’s quartic.

Thank you.

† The “different language” is PostScript, and I really don’t have the expertise to write a //PostScriptForm function. Indeed, finding the optimal balance between recomputing repeated expressions and using “… dup … roll” would, in the general case, be slow.

Comment: why are you solving for xx which isnt in the expression?

Comment: Editing error: substitute xstep. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a package called "Substitutions" ([archived here](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/TechNotes/4274/)), which pulls out a hierarchy of sub-expressions, minimizing the coding for complex expressions.  It was included in the old MathSource library. Here's the description:

> It is often useful, especially when using Mathematica for software
>   development, to apply substitutions to complex expressions to reduce
>   their form. For large expressions, this task can become tedious.
>   Substitutions[] was designed help with the process of finding a useful
>   set of substitutions to simplify an expression.

It is quite old now, but should still work.

Answer (score 0):

Reduce may be what you want:

I've consolodated some of your symbol groups into A,B,C (not nesesary, makes it fit on screen)

```
Reduce[{dist^2 == xstep^2 + (A)^2 && 
        dist^2 == (C - NC xstep)^2 + (B - dist/2)^2 , {xstep, dist}]]
```

this produces a fairly large output with a bunch of conditions.

If you have known constraints that preclude various degenrate cases it helps to specify (I made these up)

```
$Assumptions = B != 0  && B^2 != 3 C^2  && NC^2 != 3/4;
```

note $Assumptions is used by Simplify, but you need to explicitly add it to the Reduce expression..

```
Simplify[Reduce[{dist^2 == xstep^2 + (A)^2 && 
    dist^2 == (C - NC xstep)^2 + (B - dist/2)^2  && $Assumptions }, {xstep, dist}]]
```

output.. not too unwiledy .. The Root expression contains the coefficients you seek..

```
 (xstep == 
      Root[9 A^4 - 40 A^2 B^2 + 16 B^4 - 24 A^2 C^2 + 32 B^2 C^2 + 
   16 C^4 + (48 A^2 C NC - 64 B^2 C NC - 
      64 C^3 NC) #1 + (18 A^2 - 40 B^2 - 24 C^2 - 24 A^2 NC^2 + 
      32 B^2 NC^2 + 96 C^2 NC^2) #1^2 + (48 C NC - 
      64 C NC^3) #1^3 + (9 - 24 NC^2 + 16 NC^4) #1^4 &, 1] || 
   xstep == 
    Root[9 A^4 - 40 A^2 B^2 + 16 B^4 - 24 A^2 C^2 + 32 B^2 C^2 + 
      16 C^4 + (48 A^2 C NC - 64 B^2 C NC - 
       64 C^3 NC) #1 + (18 A^2 - 40 B^2 - 24 C^2 - 24 A^2 NC^2 + 
       32 B^2 NC^2 + 96 C^2 NC^2) #1^2 + (48 C NC - 
       64 C NC^3) #1^3 + (9 - 24 NC^2 + 16 NC^4) #1^4 &, 2] || 
  xstep == 
   Root[9 A^4 - 40 A^2 B^2 + 16 B^4 - 24 A^2 C^2 + 32 B^2 C^2 + 
   16 C^4 + (48 A^2 C NC - 64 B^2 C NC - 
      64 C^3 NC) #1 + (18 A^2 - 40 B^2 - 24 C^2 - 24 A^2 NC^2 + 
      32 B^2 NC^2 + 96 C^2 NC^2) #1^2 + (48 C NC - 
      64 C NC^3) #1^3 + (9 - 24 NC^2 + 16 NC^4) #1^4 &, 3] || 
   xstep == 
    Root[9 A^4 - 40 A^2 B^2 + 16 B^4 - 24 A^2 C^2 + 32 B^2 C^2 + 
    16 C^4 + (48 A^2 C NC - 64 B^2 C NC - 
      64 C^3 NC) #1 + (18 A^2 - 40 B^2 - 24 C^2 - 24 A^2 NC^2 + 
      32 B^2 NC^2 + 96 C^2 NC^2) #1^2 + (48 C NC - 
      64 C NC^3) #1^3 + (9 - 24 NC^2 + 16 NC^4) #1^4 &, 4]) && 
   3 A^2 + 4 B dist + xstep (8 C NC + 3 xstep) == 
       4 (B^2 + C^2 + NC^2 xstep^2)
```

Comment: Hmmm. Progress, thank you. That’s different to Solve[]. In particular, it gives a Root[…] for xstep, but not for dist. One could solve the xstep polynomial, and then solve for dist, but there should be a direct one-step Root[…] for dist. Please, is that reachable?

Comment: try changing the order of the solution variables ( `{ dist,xstep}` ).

Comment: Thank you, but that doesn’t work in the likes of:  
    $Assumptions=(H\[Element]Reals&&H>0&&W\[Element]Reals&&W>H&&NR\[Element]Integers&&NR>0&&NC\[Element]Integers&&NC>0&&R\[Element]Reals&&R>0);  


    Simplify[Reduce[{(W==2R+(NC-1)XX) && (H==R(2NR-4)+2YY) && (4R^2==XX^2+YY^2) &&$Assumptions},{R,XX,YY}]]

Comment: PS: I know that, in this example, the R polynomial is easy to find. But the question asks how can I most reliably and idiomatically get Mathematica to do the work?